# How to run nested evaluations in Spring Expression Language

Tags: spring, spring-el

I want to Use SPeL and I need to evaluate a parameter from a configuration source. The problem is that the name/key is dynamic. So I rely on one parameter to resolve the other.
I basically need to check a Boolean parameter.

Example:
partial key/prefix: app.name
full key: ${app.name}.feature.isEnabled

So, in SPeL I try something like:

```
#{'${app.name}.feature.isEnabled' != null && !'${app.name}.feature.isEnabled'}
```

But this compiles but doesn't work.

If app.name=my-app, the above resolves to string literal:
my-app.feature.isEnabled

the literal in itself id ok but I actually need the value of this key.

If I try to wrap with another expression, it doesn't compile:

```
#{${'${app.name}.feature.isEnabled'} != null && !${'${app.name}.feature.isEnabled'}}
```

I tried different variations of the above but can't make it to the right formula.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to evaluate a dynamic/nested Spring property placeholder expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705322/how-to-evaluate-a-dynamic-nested-spring-property-placeholder-expression)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There might be something simpler, but this works...

```
"#{'${${app.name}.feature.isEnabled}' != null ? '${${app.name}.feature.isEnabled}'.toLowerCase().equals('true') : 'false'}"
```

But you need `ignore-unresolvable="true"` on the property placeholder configurer if the property is not set.

Comment: This doesn't work as PropertyPlaceholderHelper fails to parse and identify the inner nested property and parse return endIndex -1 (not found)

Comment: It worked fine for me. I tested it before posting. You must have a typo or something.

Comment: I am using spring boot and trying to apply it using:

@ConditionalOnExpression("#{'${${spring.application.name}.http.pingtFilter.isEnabled' != null && '${${spring.application.name}.http.pingtFilter.isEnabled'.toLowerCase().equals('false')}")

Comment: You're missing closing braces after each isEnabled. Compare with mine.

Comment: Great catch, Thanks for a great Answer.